# How to change PyCharm main folder on Windows?

Tags: python, windows, pycharm, directory

I am struggling with our company's profile space which is limited to 250 MB for profile. I use PyCharm for some python project, but the problem is that PyCharm creates folder outside My Documents in:

`C:\Users\Me\.PyCharmCE2017.3\`

I would like to move the folder to some other location which is not synced with the server or to My Documents, where space is unlimited. Is there any way to change the location of the main Pycharm folder? I was looking for it in Pycharm settings but I couldn't find the option. Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean, do you want to move your project to other path? just do it man, then use your pycharm to open the new-locationed project.  I don't know whats your issue.

Comment: You could [create a symbolic link](https://superuser.com/questions/1020821/how-to-create-a-symbolic-link-on-windows-10)

Comment: I have project in different directory anyway, I want to move PyCharm main folder with all settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution thanks to Rawing:

```
mklink /D "C:\Users\Me\.PyCharmCE2017.3" "C:\Folder\.PyCharmCE2017.3"
```

used from Windows command line. First you have to move original folder to your directory, here C:\Folder\ and then create a link with this command. No shared space problem anymore and Pycharm works perfectly fine! Thanks!